# SMTP email in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, smtp

I have an asp.net application where email is being sent via SMTP. If a user is listed in To as well as in Cc, the user is receiving the email twice. This happens only when the application is running in Azure. Doesn't happen when running on on-premise server. Any idea what needs to change in Azure world?

Comment: This is not an Azure issue. Most likely because you are sending from an external SMTP host it is not deduplicating the sent message (To: / Cc:) where you on-prem SMTP server (Exchange by any chance?) is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's how it should be and there is nothing wrong. It's not related to `Azure` at all. Ty testing the same in your office SMTP server and you will see same effect.

You should remove the recipient from `cc` list if it's not meant to be present.

Comment: No, when sent from office SMTP, it is received only once